# Can I reference an image on a different subdomain in structured data?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I have `www.example.com` for which I'll be building structured data. The website logo and all other images are on the assets subdomain at `subdomain.example.com`.

Will structured data references still work even if the assets are not on the same subdomain as the page?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Structured data is about connecting information across the internet.

Update:

Googles guidelines for logo do not mention any restriction on the location of the logo:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo

Nor does the underlying specification for logo or url:

https://schema.org/logo
https://schema.org/URL

In practice, many sites place their images in a CDN which is often a completely different domain. They have no issue with structured data.

You can also test your structured data using tools like the Rich Results Test. It does not report any issues when URLs form other domains are used.

Comment: I think, the correct and exhaustive answer on the question `Will structured data references still work` is yes or no. TS doesn't asked about details. However, in case of `no` i would consider to add some details to achieve the `yes`. But this wasn't the case here.